# @Input with promise Angular2

Tags: angular

I have the parent component like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { UrlService } from '../../services/url.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'wrapPost',
   templateUrl: './app/html/wrapPost.component.html',
})

export class WrapPost {
    dataPost: any;
    url: string;

    constructor(private urlService: UrlService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        let url = window.location.pathname;
        this.urlService.getData(url)
            .then(res => this.dataPost = res);
    }
}
```

there is get a dates from server and return **this.dataPost**.
That's well working.

This html of parent `templateUrl: './app/html/wrapPost.component.html'`

```
<div class="noteCommonAlign">

    <navigation></navigation>
    <posts [dataPost]="dataPost"></posts>
    <loading class="noteCommonAlign"></loading>
    <pagination [dataPost]="dataPost"></pagination>

</div>
```

Further the component **pagination** (the child)

```
import { Component, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'pagination',
   templateUrl: './app/html/pagination.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['app/css/pagination.component.css']
})

export class Pagination {
   pagCurrent: number;
   @Input() dataPost: any;

   constructor(){
   }
    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
        try{
       console.log(this.dataPost);
     } catch(err) {
       console.log(err);
     }
    }
}
```

I can't get **this.dataPost** async. When i called without *ngOnChanges* console.log(this.dataPost) then happen a mistake.  I resolved this problem a little. I Used **ngOnChanges** but in console showed 2 messages. One message with a mistake other with a great result.

How i understand it has happen because **ngOnChanges** is Lifecycle and called before ngOnInit and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change.
I wouldn't like that it's called twice.

How to get a dates from server in a child component has @Input?

I'm sorry for the grammar. I will be glad any solves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```ts
<navigation></navigation>
<posts [dataPost]="dataPost | async"></posts>
<loading class="noteCommonAlign"></loading>
<pagination [dataPost]="dataPost | async"></pagination>
```

**update**

With this code

```ts
ngOnInit(){
    this.urlService.getData()
        .then(res => this.dataPost = res);
}
```

You don't need `| async` because `this.dataPost` gets the categories assigned, not the `Promise`.

If you change it to

```ts
ngOnInit(){
    this.dataPost = this.urlService.getData();
        //.then(res => this.dataPost = res);
}
```

then using `| async` is approriate, but if you actually use `| async`

```ts
<pagination [dataPost]="dataPost | async"></pagination>
```

then

```ts
@Input() dataPost: Promise<any>;
```

gets passed the categories, not the promise because `| async` already resolves the promise to get the categories.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YsTPMiCmzjg7x0aM5RiQ?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried to do like this but poorly. I removed `ngOnChanges` and running `console.log(this.dataPost)` in costructor but a bad result `undefined`. I think it's not getting async. Can you help how solve is it?

Comment: Also `dataPost$: any;` can't resolve this problem. When i get something from server and show in`ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.dataPost);
   }` then return a result like this `null`.

Comment: How does `urlService.getData` look like? The value is not yet available in `ngAfterViewInit`. If `urlService.getData` makes a call to the server, this takes an eternity compared to code that is executed only in the browser. You need to chain all async calls with `.then(...)` for promises or operators like `.map()`, `.do()`, `.subscribe(...)` for observables. When `ngAfterViewInit` is executed the call to the server probably isn't event sent yet.

Comment: `urlService.getData` like this `getData(url): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({name}))
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
    }`
Yes. I have in my code `.then(...)`. So `this.urlService.getData(url)
            .then(res => this.dataPost = res);` is getting Promise<any>. I change `@Input() dataPost: any;` -> `@Input() dataPost: Promise<any>;`
Then if in `pagination.component.ts (the child)` to call `ngOnInit(){console.log(this.dataPost)}` then get a mistake

Comment: Invalid argument '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'. The server send Object but why?

Comment: I use `.then(...)` anywhere and `@Input() dataPost: Promise<any>;`.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker. It's quite difficult for me to follow what exactly you're doing from some fragments. (Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template under the `new` button)

Comment: thanks alt you answer helped me a lot when using input property :)